# How do I start Foreman server on background on production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, digital-ocean, foreman

I have successfully deployed my rails Application on a VPS using Ubuntu server with Digital ocean. I am using foreman to start many processes, I can start my foreman server with `foreman start` if I ssh into my server but when I close the terminal all the processes stop. how do I make it run continuously on the background?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- ssh into the remote machine
- start tmux by typing tmux into the shell
- start the process you want inside the started tmux session
- leave/detach the tmux session by typing Ctrl+B and then D

You can now safely logoff from the remote machine, your process will keep running inside tmux. When you come back again and want to check the status of your process you can use tmux attach to attach to your tmux session.

If you want to have multiple session running side-by-side you should name each session using Ctrl-B and $. You can get a list of the currently running sessions using tmux list-sessions.

tmux can do much more advanced things then handle a single window in a single session. For more information have a look in man tmux or http://tmux.github.io/ . A FAQ about the main differences between screen and tmux is available here.

Answer (score 11):

A better question would be "how do I run a Rails application as a service?".

Foreman is a great tool for development, but it does not offer process supervision, automatic start on server up, log rotation or the ability to manage processes with Unix signals.

If your Ubuntu is 15.04, you have systemd installed, and should use that instead. Foreman can even export your config via `foreman export systemd` (see [the foreman manpage](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/)).
If your Ubuntu is older than that, you will have Upstart, which, again, Foreman can export to (`foreman export upstart`).

Using nohup, screen or tmux for running processes is horrible advice and will make your life unnecessarily hard even in the short run.

Comment: This is not true. I need foreman in the background on my dev machine. Mainly because I want a migrate script that performs `git pull; rake db:migrate` but needs my postgresql, redis, etc. running while that happens. The bash script would have performed `foreman start -f updateonly.yml &; PID=$?` then when finished `kill $PID` But foreman is being stupid and needing a tmux or screen instance. Seriously WTF? how is that composible?! (Unix rule of composition)